# Class field with different argument types (setter overloading)

Tags: kotlin, properties

I have a class with a field of type long and I would like to pass either an Int or a Long value.

So I thought I can make a second setter with the same name, but different argument.
Kotlin does not complain and I can even call both setters from Java (same name, one automatically created with long from Kotlin). In Java I just call setMyNumber(long or int) value and the compiler will assign the correct method.

But why can't I do `myNumber = 4` in Kotlin, why does it not call the other setter?
Is there a different way I can achieve this functionality, but still keep the property notation (yes I know I can write to setter methods, but then I have to call them with a method call rather just assigning a value)?

```
class MyClass {

    var myNumber: Long = 0L // internal setMyNumber(value: Long)

    fun setMyNumber(newNumber: Int) {
        myNumber = newNumber.toLong()
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no implicit _internal setMyNumber(value: Long)_ as you have in your comment. _myNumber_ is just a property with no setter and getter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of writing, what you're trying to do is not supported. (See: [Allow setters overloading for properties](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4075/Allow-setters-overloading-for-properties))

A workaround would be using the Superclass for all platform classes representing numeric values:

```kotlin
class MyClass {
    var myNumber: Number = 0L
        set (value) { field = value.toLong() }
}

val myClass = MyClass()

val anInt: Int = 1
val aLong: Long = 1L

myClass.myNumber = anInt
myClass.myNumber = aLong
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jU69CsIwEN7zFDcmS3FwkGAFcRKqi08QNS3B9CpJWiilz14vabspeMMdfN99P68mWIPT9LDKe7j0p3QHBjSdclD317a@aydhvpDDpkhsHK8D8E7ZVgsYoDTaPukhAVloigYrLmBkI2OsbBFqZZArV3kJR@dUv78FZ7A6iBRIMoqbC@RrFS7YQik8Y5BAi9jtCsYMCXETuivi8@KRrdWJSNovVGZ14FK@qUWwKH6po/0f6nGaPg)

Comment: Thanks for the link for 'Allow setter overloading'.